# How to generate Password Reset Token in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to generate password reset token in Magento 2.

In magento 1, I was generating token by using below code -

```
$oldtoken = $cust->getRpToken();
$newResetPasswordLinkToken = Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
$cust->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);`
```

But not sure how to generate in magento 2.

I have search complete `/vendor/magento/module-customer` but not able to generate Token.

**Edit -**

Code for Magento 2 -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Helper\View');
$newResetPasswordLinkToken = $helper->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
$cust->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the helper `\Magento\User\Helper\Data`, it's located on `vendor/magento/module-user/Helper/Data.php`. Then find the function `generateResetPasswordLinkToken()` on line 50.

**======Update on 19:00 16 Jun 2017======**

Per user request, I added an example to get token using DI

```
class XXXX{
    protected $_userHelper;

    /* Other DIs come here */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\User\Helper\Data $user_helper,
        /* Other DIs come here */
    ) {
        $this->_userHelper= $user_helper;
        /* Other DIs come here */
    }

    /* The function name is up to you */
    public function getToken(){
        return $this->_userHelper->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
    }
    /* other functions */
}
```

Comment: There is no Data.php file at `vendor/magento/module-customer/Helper`  in Magento 2.1.3

Comment: Sorry, should be `vendor/magento/module-user/Helper/Data.php`

Comment: please check my updated code for magneto 2

Comment: I recommend you to use Dependency Injection rather than Object Manager

Comment: can u please give example?

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: @PYYick can you give an working example of how to actually get the final url link for say user "foo"? thanks.

Comment: Insert my code into a controller, then call this URL. You may refer to official docs to see how to build a controller.

Answer (score 6):

Find below

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php
```

Please find `public function initiatePasswordReset($email, $template, $websiteId = null)`

you can get it from line 505, as below

```
$newPasswordToken = $this->mathRandom->getUniqueHash();
$this->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($customer, $newPasswordToken);
```

======== Reset Password Token for Customer ============

```
class YOURCLASSNAME {

    protected $_accountmanagement;
    private $_customerRepository;
    private $_mathRandom;

    /* Other DIs come here */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $accountmanagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        /* Other DIs come here */
    ) {
        $this->_accountmanagement= $accountmanagement;
        $this->_customerRepository= $customerRepository;
        $this->_mathRandom= $mathRandom;
        /* Other DIs come here */
    }

    /* The function name is up to you */
    public function getToken($email, $websiteId){
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->get($email, $websiteId);

        $newPasswordToken = $this->_mathRandom->getUniqueHash();
        $this->_accountmanagement->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($customer, $newPasswordToken);
    }
    /* other functions */
}
```

Comment: please check my updated code for magneto 2. Can u please provide example

Comment: @RahulDambare for whom you want to generate token admin user or customer?

Comment: Customer user. Now my final code is `$helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\User\Helper\Data');
 $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  $helper->generateResetPasswordLinkToken(); 
 echo "\n\nToken - " . $newResetPasswordLinkToken . "\n\n";
 $cust->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);`

Comment: @RahulDambare Sorry to sound like a beaten drum, but using objectManager is not the right way of doing this.

Comment: use forgot password event dont need to write extra function for rp token