# Magento2: send a password reset url with customer's email

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I would like to send customer a link to have their password reseted.

**=> Code :**

```
$customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
    $customer=$customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId(1);

$customer->loadByEmail($email);// load customer by email address

    $data= $customer->getData();
    print_r ($data);
```

However I cannot see any info here like a url that I can generate to then send to the customer.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I remember you, you asked this on one of my answers before. So here is the details of creating a controller to call the reset password link.

1. Create `routes.xml` under `app/code/<Vendor_Name>/<Module_Name>/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
       <router id="standard">
           <route id="<route_id>" frontName="<route_id>">
               <module name="<Vendor_Name>_<Module_Name>" />
           </route>
       </router>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create a controller file. Let's say, you want the URL to me `<website_url>/<route_id>/password/reset`, then you need to create a file with the path `app/code/<Vendor_Name>/<Module_Name>/Controller/Password/Reset.php`

   ```
   <?php
   namespace <Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Controller\Password;

   use \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
   use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
   use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

   class Reset extends Action
   {
       protected $customerFactory;

       public function __construct(
           Context $context,
           CustomerFactory $customerFactory
       )
       {
           parent::__construct($context);
           $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
       }

       public function execute()
       {
           //This is your code
           $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
           $customer->setWebsiteId(1);
           $customer->loadByEmail($email);
           $data = $customer->getData();
           print_r($data)
       }
   }
   ```

Then, refer to my answer, get the password reset url by changing the codes inside `execute()`. In case of you forgot the question, here it is: [How to generate Password Reset Token in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179390/how-to-generate-password-reset-token-in-magento-2/179394?noredirect=1#comment269057_179394)

P.S: Avoid using `$objectManager` directly.

Comment: ah I see your response now.  I'm a bit niave and for me using the $objectManager makes so much sense.  I don't get the whole concept of a controller and how to execute it.  For example with a objectManger I can just call that within a PHP script and the necessary processing.  I think I will have to study this a bit more.  For example say I have a boostrap php that I use to do some processing, say create a new user; how would I incorporate this into my code?

Comment: Just put `$objectManager->get(<class_name>);` to `__construct` instead. For details please see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html